# SQL query runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio but when I run it from VBA it returns blank

Tags: sql-server, vba, ssms

Here is the code. Is there something that can't run from Excel? I've tested the SQL code in Excel by outputting the text to a cell and copying to SQL Server Management Studio and running and it works fine.

Thanks in advance

```sql
Declare @GroupNumber as varchar(5)
Declare @GroupName as varchar(max)
Declare @ValuationDate as Date
Declare @GroupStartDate as Date
Declare @GroupAnniversayDate as Date
Declare @ValuationYRMO as varchar(6)
Declare @PlanCode as varchar(6)

--**************************Change Here*********
Set @GroupNumber = '01142'
Set @ValuationDate = '08-31-2019'
--**************************************************

Set @ValuationYRMO = convert(varchar(6),year(@ValuationDate)*100 + month(@ValuationDate))

--****************** Delete Temp Tables
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Census') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #Census
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RateTablePrepStep1') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #RateTablePrepStep1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RateTablePrepStep2') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #RateTablePrepStep2
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RateTable') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #RateTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MembershipData') IS NOT NULL
            drop table ##MembershipData
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Membership') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #Membership
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ClaimData') IS NOT NULL
            drop table ##ClaimData
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Claims') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #Claims
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Completion') IS NOT NULL
            drop table ##Completion
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ValuationDates') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #ValuationDates
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PaymentStatus') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #PaymentStatus
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#InvoiceData') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #InvoiceData
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AgentGroup') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #AgentGroup
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GroupEarnedPremium') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #GroupEarnedPremium
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EarnedPremium') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #EarnedPremium
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PaymentFrequency') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #PaymentFrequency
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#InvoiceWOTax') IS NOT NULL
            drop table #InvoiceWOTax

--****************** Start Date and Anniversary Date
Set @GroupStartDate = (Select top 1 a.FirstEffectiveDate
                                    From [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a
                                    left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyGroup] b on a.PolicyGroupId=b.PolicyGroupId
                                    where b.GroupNumber=@GroupNumber)
Set @GroupAnniversayDate = (Select top 1  a.RenewalDate
                                    From [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a
                                    left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyGroup] b on a.PolicyGroupId=b.PolicyGroupId
                                    where b.GroupNumber=@GroupNumber)

--****************** Census
SELECT distinct b.GroupNumber,
                         Case when b.[Description] is null then pl.[name] else b.[description] end as [Group Name],
                         ps.[name] as [Group Status],
                         cc.[name] as [Group Country],
                         b1.GroupNumber as Subsidiary,
                         a2.PolicyId as [Certificate], 
                         ps2.[name] as [Certificate Status],
                         me.MemberId,
                         con.FirstName as [First Name],
                         con.LastName as [Last Name],
                         mt.[name] as [Member Type],
                         ms.[Name] as [Member Status],
                         con.DateOfBirth as [Date of Birth],
                         Case when @ValuationDate > = dateadd(year,year(@ValuationDate)-year(con.DateOfBirth),con.DateOfBirth)  
                                          then year(@ValuationDate)-year(con.DateOfBirth) 
                                          else year(@ValuationDate)-year(con.DateOfBirth) -1 end as Age,
                         ge.[name] as Gender,
                         pl.[Code],
                         pl.[Name] as [Plan Name],
                         po.[name] as [Plan Option]
  into #Census
  FROM [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a
  left join [Actuarial].CurrentMonth.[PolicyAdminPolicyCountry] pc on a.PolicyId=pc.PolicyId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericCountry] cc on pc.CountryId=cc.CountryId and pc.EndDate is null
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericStatus] ps on a.StatusId=ps.StatusId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyGroup] b on a.PolicyGroupId=b.PolicyGroupId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a1 on a.policyid=a1.ParentPolicyId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyGroup] b1 on a1.PolicyGroupId=b1.PolicyGroupId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a2 on a1.policyid=a2.ParentPolicyId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericStatus] ps2 on a2.StatusId=ps2.StatusId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyEligibility] pe on a2.policyid=pe.PolicyId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[ProductConfigPlan] pl on pe.PlanId=pl.PlanId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminMemberEligibility] me on pe.PolicyEligibilityId=me.PolicyEligibilityId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericStatus] ms on me.StatusId=ms.StatusId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[ProductConfigPlanOption] po on me.PlanOptionId=po.PlanOptionId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[ProductConfigMemberType] mt on me.MemberTypeId=mt.MemberTypeId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminMember] mem on me.MemberId=mem.MemberId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[ContactMgmtContact] con on mem.ContactId=con.ContactId
  left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericGender] ge on con.GenderId=ge.GenderId

   where b.GroupNumber=@GroupNumber and pe.EndDate is null and me.EndDate is null
   order by b.groupnumber,b1.GroupNumber,a2.PolicyId

   select * from #census order by [GroupNumber],Subsidiary,[Plan Option],[Certificate]
```

I'm stuck on how to proceed. I've tested my record connection with a simple top 10 query and that works fine from VBA.

Here is my VBA code:

```
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rst2 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQueryBase As String
    Dim StrQueryBase2 As String
    Dim StrQueryBase3 As String
    Dim StrQueryGroupDate As String
    Dim StrQueryCensus As String
    Dim StrQueryCensus2 As String
    Dim StrQueryCensus3 As String
    Dim StrQueryTest As String

    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=bddc1didw1;Initial Catalog=Actuarial; Trusted_connection=Yes; Integrated Security='SSPI'"
    'Opens connection to the database
    cnn.Open ConnectionString

    'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; this will run for 15 minutes before VBA timesout, but your database might timeout before this value
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 1500


    StrQueryBase = "Declare @GroupNumber as varchar(5) " & _
                    "Declare @GroupName as varchar(max) " & _
                    "Declare @ValuationDate as Date " & _
                    "Declare @GroupStartDate as Date " & _
                    "Declare @GroupAnniversayDate as Date " & _
                    "Declare @ValuationYRMO as varchar(6) " & _
                    "Declare @PlanCode as varchar(6) " & _
"Set @GroupNumber = '01142' " & _
"Set @ValuationDate = '08-31-2019'  " & _
"Set @ValuationYRMO = convert(varchar(6),year(@ValuationDate)*100 + month(@ValuationDate)) " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Census') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #Census " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RateTablePrepStep1') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #RateTablePrepStep1 " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RateTablePrepStep2') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #RateTablePrepStep2 " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RateTable') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #RateTable " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MembershipData') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table ##MembershipData " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Membership') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #Membership "

    StrQueryBase2 = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ClaimData') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table ##ClaimData " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Claims') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #Claims " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Completion') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table ##Completion " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ValuationDates') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #ValuationDates " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PaymentStatus') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #PaymentStatus " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#InvoiceData') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #InvoiceData " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AgentGroup') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #AgentGroup " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GroupEarnedPremium') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #GroupEarnedPremium " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EarnedPremium') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #EarnedPremium " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PaymentFrequency') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #PaymentFrequency " & _
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#InvoiceWOTax') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "drop table #InvoiceWOTax " & _
"Set @GroupStartDate = (Select top 1 a.FirstEffectiveDate " & _
                                    "From [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a " & _
                                    "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyGroup] b on a.PolicyGroupId=b.PolicyGroupId "

StrQueryBase3 = "where b.GroupNumber=@GroupNumber) " & _
"Set @GroupAnniversayDate = (Select top 1  a.RenewalDate " & _
                                    "From [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a " & _
                                    "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyGroup] b on a.PolicyGroupId=b.PolicyGroupId " & _
                                    "where b.GroupNumber=@GroupNumber) "


   StrQueryCensus = "SELECT distinct b.GroupNumber, " & _
                         "Case when b.[Description] is null then pl.[name] else b.[description] end as [Group Name], " & _
                         "ps.[name] as [Group Status], " & _
                         "cc.[name] as [Group Country], " & _
                         "b1.GroupNumber as Subsidiary, " & _
                         "a2.PolicyId as [Certificate], " & _
                         "ps2.[name] as [Certificate Status], " & _
                         "me.MemberId, " & _
                         "con.FirstName as [First Name], " & _
                         "con.LastName as [Last Name], " & _
                         "mt.[name] as [Member Type], " & _
                         "ms.[Name] as [Member Status], " & _
                         "con.DateOfBirth as [Date of Birth], " & _
                         "Case when @ValuationDate > = dateadd(year,year(@ValuationDate)-year(con.DateOfBirth),con.DateOfBirth) " & _
                                          "then year(@ValuationDate)-year(con.DateOfBirth) " & _
                                          "else year(@ValuationDate)-year(con.DateOfBirth) -1 end as Age, " & _
                         "ge.[name] as Gender, " & _
                         "pl.[Code], " & _
                         "pl.[Name] as [Plan Name], " & _
                         "po.[name] as [Plan Option] " & _
  "into #Census " & _
  "FROM [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].CurrentMonth.[PolicyAdminPolicyCountry] pc on a.PolicyId=pc.PolicyId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericCountry] cc on pc.CountryId=cc.CountryId and pc.EndDate is null "


   StrQueryCensus2 = "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericStatus] ps on a.StatusId=ps.StatusId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyGroup] b on a.PolicyGroupId=b.PolicyGroupId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a1 on a.policyid=a1.ParentPolicyId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyGroup] b1 on a1.PolicyGroupId=b1.PolicyGroupId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicy] a2 on a1.policyid=a2.ParentPolicyId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericStatus] ps2 on a2.StatusId=ps2.StatusId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminPolicyEligibility] pe on a2.policyid=pe.PolicyId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[ProductConfigPlan] pl on pe.PlanId=pl.PlanId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminMemberEligibility] me on pe.PolicyEligibilityId=me.PolicyEligibilityId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericStatus] ms on me.StatusId=ms.StatusId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[ProductConfigPlanOption] po on me.PlanOptionId=po.PlanOptionId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[ProductConfigMemberType] mt on me.MemberTypeId=mt.MemberTypeId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[PolicyAdminMember] mem on me.MemberId=mem.MemberId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[ContactMgmtContact] con on mem.ContactId=con.ContactId " & _
  "left join [Actuarial].[CurrentMonth].[GenericGender] ge on con.GenderId=ge.GenderId " & _
  "where b.GroupNumber=@GroupNumber and pe.EndDate is null and me.EndDate is null " & _
  "order by b.groupnumber,b1.GroupNumber,a2.PolicyId " & _
  "select * from #census order by [GroupNumber],Subsidiary,[Plan Option],[Certificate] "

  StrQueryCensus3 = StrQueryBase & StrQueryBase2 & StrQueryBase3 & StrQueryCensus & StrQueryCensus2 "

'
      ActiveSheet.Range("e1") = StrQueryCensus3




     rst2.Open StrQueryCensus3, cnn

    ActiveSheet.Range("e2").CopyFromRecordset rst2
```

Comment: I should add that all parts up to "****** Census" are correct and working fine as I have used it for a different query that is working.

Comment: If the first half of the script works, there is no reason I know of why the second half wouldn't work. Are your sure Excel is connecting to the same DB that you are using in Management Studio?

Comment: Yes because i've tested it by doing a simple select top 1 query from the same database and it gave me the correct results.

Comment: Weird. I would reduce your script down to the bit you know works, and then build it up again bit by bit to see at what point it stops working

Comment: well the problem is i know it works up until the join as i've used that part in a different working query, But then the join and corresponding select is one part. Which all works in sql when copied directly from the output of the stringquery field.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using temp tables in SQL from VBA?

Comment: Please post your Excel VBA code. Multiple SQL statements usually are not allowed in an ADO (assuming this is your DB-API) `OpenRecordset` or `Execute` call. Better to wrap entire process in a stored procedure and call that object in VBA.

Comment: Here is my VBA code, added to post